# Passenger on Apache 2 Installation fails with Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old

Tags: apache, apache2, rvm, passenger, ubuntu-10.04

I'm trying to install passenger on a virtual rootserver (which has multiple user accounts) but running 'passenger-install-apache2-module' results always in the following error:

Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old. Please update them first by running 'rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'.

Following this given instructions does not take any effect. 
Before installing passenger, i installed RVM as multiuser / mixed mode according to https://rvm.io//rvm/install/

After that I did (using a non root-account):

- rvmsudo rvm user gemsets
- rvm install 1.9.3
- gem install rails
- gem install passenger
- and lastly passenger-install-apache2-module

I searched for hours on this problem but could not find any working solution yet. 
Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any news on this ? I'm facing the same issue (10 months later).

Comment: @Elmatou I've just had some success, check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try to install passenger-install-apache2-module like this :

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this very same issue. I'm using ZSH, but switching to Bash also failed on first attempt.

My solution was to switch to Bash with the `--login` flag:

```
/bin/bash --login
```

Then I noticed that my RVM ruby had become unset, so I re-set using:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3 --default
```

Once this was done, the following worked as expected:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Rich

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue and have taken extreme steps on my centos 6.3 system after struggling for days! In specific, I failed to install standalone phusion passenger apache2 module on gemsets other than default and global. I have taken the following steps and now, it works for me:

1. Login as root (I hope you know what you're dealing with)
2. To completely uninstall existing rvm, invoke
   [root#] rvm implode
3. Install stable rvm, invoke 
   [root#] curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
4. run rvm shell, 
   [root#] source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
5. check rvm requirements, invoke 
   [root#] rvm requirements
6. and install all requirements.
7. Install ruby 1.9.3, invoke
   [root#] rvm install 1.9.3
8. Install current rubygems, invoke
   rvm rubygems current
9. Set default to ruby 1.9.3, invoke
   [root#] rvm use 1.9.3 --default
10. Add other users who are using rvm to rvm group, invoke
    [root#] usermod -a -G rvm USERNAME
11. If USERNAME is currently logged in, pls logout so the group add will take effect.
12. Make sure rvm group added, invoke
    [USERNAME#] groups
13. Create and Switch to a new gemset on ruby 1.9.3, invoke
    [USERNAME#] rvm use 1.9.3@mygemset --create
14. Confirm that you're on the right gemset, invoke
    [USERNAME#] rvm gemset name
15. Install passenger gem, invoke
    gem install passenger
16. To skip gem documentation instead, invoke
    [USERNAME#] gem install passenger --no-ri --no-rdoc
17. or specify them in your .gemrc file
18. To install apache2 mod, invoke
    [USERNAME#] passenger-install-apache2-module

Hope that helps!